# Create\Add a graph Titan server using default rexster

Tags: titan, rexster

when i run

> rexster.getGraphNames()

my only result is graph, when i ran a gremlin instance directly over titan i had

> tmp

and created a graph called

> mygraph

i have been loooking around and havent found anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titan Server will only host a single instance of a graph.  Therefore, `rexster.getGraphNames()` will always only return one graph and it will always be called `graph`.

Creating a graph called `mygraph` with the Gremlin REPL won't connect Titan Server to the graph unless you've configured it to do so and even then, it will still be referred to by Titan Server as just `graph`.

Comment: so if i have 2graphs i need to host two rexster servers to expose them ?

Comment: Titan Server goes away in Titan 0.4.x.  Aurelius benchmarking has shown that embedded cassandra generally does not perform as well as Rexster/Cassandra in separate JVMs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/aureliusgraphs/titan$20embedded/aureliusgraphs/EasJTTkDtfY/jTTBDbwyIgUJ  Going forward the recommended approach will be to install Rexster on each node in the cassandra cluster.  If you were to do that, then you have the full capability of Rexster to host as many graphs as you want in it.

Comment: Can't get the correct redirect from your search, perhaps it is this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/EasJTTkDtfY/daLyEPck4KEJ

Comment: Yeah...i think that's what i was referring to.  Wonder why the link broke.